# In MVC 4 how aspnet db mebership table create in mdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have  created  mvc4 application which by defaults implement  login and register user code. I have added userdata.mdf file in app_data folder. 
When I have run the application I got error.

What I am expecting is  aspnet_membership  tables should create  in  mdf  file which I have added. How can  I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

MVC 4 does not use the traditional ASP.NET Membership, which you seem to be referring to. When you use the Internet template to create a new MVC 4 application it uses something referred to as SimpleMembership which uses EF code-first and should automatically create a local database in the app_data folder.

Look in the web.config for the default connection string to see what the name of the file is. The default connection string I am referring to is generated by the Internet Template and looks something like this:

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication1-20120822144338;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication1-20120822144338.mdf" />
```

The database name is usually in the format of "apsnet-application name-some number".

You can [learn more about customizing SimpleMembership in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Please see the update in my answer that clarifies what I mean by a default connection string.